# Method in class can not be applied to given types (java)

Tags: java, class, methods

I'm trying to use a method from another class inside my main method and im getting an error. Its telling me that Method in class can not be applied to given types.

```
public class studentclass {
public void inputloop(String[] args){

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[][] student = new String[10][];
    Double[][] results = new Double[10][];
    Double[] total = new Double[10];


    String tableln = "";

   for(int index = 0; index < student.length; index++){
    System.out.println("\nPlease enter student " + (index+1) + "'s details");
    String userinput = scan.nextLine();
    student[index] = userinput.split(",");
    results[index] = new Double[4];

    results[index][0] = Double.parseDouble(student[index][2]); 
    results[index][1] = Double.parseDouble(student[index][3]);
    results[index][2] = Double.parseDouble(student[index][4]);
    results[index][3] = Double.parseDouble(student[index][5]);
    total[index] = (results[index][0]*0.1+results[index][1]*0.4+
                    results[index][2]*0.2+results[index][3]*0.3);

    System.out.println("\nStudent name\tFAN \t\tResult1\tResult2\tResult3\tResult4\tTotal");
    tableln = tableln + "\n" + student[index][0] + "\t" + student[index][1] + "\t"
             + results[index][0] + "\t" + results[index][1] + "\t" + results[index][2] + "\t"
             + results[index][3] + "\t" + total[index];
    System.out.println(tableln);
    }
}
```

and then in my main method I type this.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    studentclass info = new studentclass();
    info.inputloop();
    }
```

It says "Method inputloop in class studentclass can not be applied to given types. required String[] found no arguements." Please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method declaration shows that it expects to be passed a reference to an array of strings:

```
public void inputloop(String[] args)
```

So you can only call the method in its current form if you pass in a value of type `String[]`.

However, you're not actually *using* `args` anywhere within the method, so I suggest you just change the declaration to:

```
public void inputloop()
```

I suggest you read the [section on defining methods in the Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html), or find a section about declaring (and calling) methods in a good introductory book on Java. If you don't currently *have* a book from which you're learning Java, I suggest you get hold of one very soon. While Stack Overflow is great for answering specific questions, it's not good for learning basic concepts - there's a *lot* more to declaring and calling methods than is present in *any* of the answers to this particular question, and learning all of it one little bit at a time is very inefficient.

Comment: ahhh, Yes it worked. I'm obviously still new. I have a book Addison & Wesley java software solutions. But some things still don't make sense to me. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Michael: I'm glad you've got a book - hopefully it's a good one, although I don't know that one specifically. Definitely reread the section on method signatures and what they mean.

Answer (score 3):

The signature of your method is:

```
public void inputloop(String[] args)
```

You should pass an array of Strings to the method:

```
info.inputloop(someStringArray);
```

See [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html) for more info:

> The parameter list in parenthesis—a comma-delimited list of input
>   parameters, preceded by their data types, enclosed by parentheses, ().
>   If there are no parameters, you must use empty parentheses.

I don't see that you're using this parameter, so you can simply change your method signature to

```
public void inputloop()
```

And now it'll be a valid call as you did it.

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to use `inputloop` when the method should get array of strings.

i'm guessing the idea was to pass the command line `args` to it. do:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
   studentclass info = new studentclass();
   info.inputloop(args);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    studentclass info = new studentclass();
    String[] student ={"John", "Mark"};
    info.inputloop(student);
    }
}
```

or

you can change public void inputloop(String[] args) to
public void inputloop()  as the input argument is never used